# Pass the JSON extractor Ref name to another request sequentailly in Jmeter which is outside the loop

Tags: json, jmeter

I have used While controller in Jmeter and fetching the data (i.e JSON _id values) one by one from the Response. total there are 50 Id's/per response.

1. E.g.
        "_id: "57565556654","_id":"68676665555", "_id": "87686877545"

*Http Request* -  When this request is submitted  I am getting _id from the response. 
Used JSON extractor to fetch the _id's from the Response. i.e. 50 ids. Ref Name = DeleteQuestionsID

In Debug Sampler DeleteQuestionsID_MatchNr shows  DeleteQuestionsID_MatchNr =1, bcoz JSOn extarctor is running inside While loop

I need to Pass these 50 Id's one by one to Next Http request which is outside the While loop.

*Http Request* : `'/v1/tests/'$'{TestID}/questions/${DeleteQuestionsID}

`How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) by adding [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor and using the following code:

```
vars.put('DeleteQuestionsID_' + vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx'), vars.get('DeleteQuestionsID'))
```

It will generate 50 JMeter Variables like:

```
DeleteQuestionsID_0=foo
DeleteQuestionsID_1=bar
DeleteQuestionsID_2=baz
etc.
```

which can re-use later on where required.

`vars` is a shorhand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope, check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is why [ForEach_Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) created for

> ForEach controller loops through the values of a set of related variables. When you add samplers (or controllers) to a ForEach controller, every sample (or controller) is executed one or more times, where during every loop the variable has a new value. The input should consist of several variables, each extended with an underscore and a number. Each such variable must have a value. So for example when the input variable has the name inputVar, the following variables should have been defined:
>
> ```
> inputVar_1 = wendy
> inputVar_2 = charles
> ```